# I do not understand why some google fonts work and other don't

Tags: css

I tried to use 'Merriweather' font from google fonts and it didn't work. Then I tried 'Raleway' and this worked fine. Why is this happening? There was literally no typo in my code.

Comment: Provide your code so we can regenerate your problem and provide a fix for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely did a typo
because it's working just fine
just make sure you selected the font, copied the link tags to you page, and add `font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;`